# Unable to commit a Stored Procedure execution using PYODBC and SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm having a hard time getting commits to the DB using SQLALCHEMY. When I call the execute_no_return function, the stored procedure I'm calling runs, but doesn't commit it's changes. The other function using PANDAS to insert works fine. Not sure what to try anymore...

Also, am I using the Session()? Found that here yesterday and haven't made sense of it yet.

```
import configparser
import pyodbc as msodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker



class connection(object) :
  def connect(self) :
    self.conn = None
    self.sess = None
    
    conf = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    conf.read_file(open(r'/path/to/directory/config'))

    engine = create_engine("""mssql+pyodbc://%s:%s@%s:1433/%s?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server""" % (conf.get('DB', 'UID'),conf.get('DB', 'PWD'),conf.get('DB', 'SERVER'),conf.get('DB', 'DATABASE')),echo=False)
    self.conn = engine

    Session = sessionmaker()
    Session.configure(bind=engine,autocommit=True)
    self.sess = Session()


  def select(self,sql) :
    self.connect()
    df = pd.read_sql(sql,self.conn)

    return df


  def insert(self,df,tbl,exists) :
    self.connect()
    df.to_sql(tbl,con=self.conn,if_exists=exists,chunksize=1000,method='multi',index=False)
    

  def run(self,sql) :
    self.connect()
    self.conn.execute(sql)


db = connection()

def select_to_dataframe(sql) :
  df = db.select(sql)
  return df


def insert_dataframe(df,tbl,exists) :
  db.insert(df,tbl,exists)


def execute_no_return(sql) :
  db.run(sql)
```

Thanks for taking a moment to assist :)

Comment: I used your code to update my own database (SQL Svr) and the update committed correctly. Perhaps your database does not auto-commit.

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed lol. Turns out my code was smarter than me, and the 700 records that "weren't committing" were being ignored and not inserted to begin with. Discovered our App is deleting records, and leaving foreign key relationships. The data warehouse wanted nothing to do with them. Thanks for bringing me a new perspective to find this "feature"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with our Application deleting records  This code works perfectly. Thanks to [@Mike76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13878034/mike67) for bringing me a new angle of attack. I would have beat on this for days!